# Why can't I set this element reference as a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object as such (simplified).

```
var MyObject = (function(){

  var propertyOne = $('.links li:first-child');
  var propertyTwo = $('.links .active');

  function startup()
  {
    propertyOne.addClass("class");  //Works
    propertyTwo.addClass("class2");  //Does not work
    $('.links .active').addClass("class2");  // Works
  }

  return {
     init: function()
     {
       startup();
     }
  }
});
```

What's the difference in the way I'm selecting propertyOne and propertyTwo?  I don't understand why

```
propertyOne.addClass("class");  //Works
$('.links .active').addClass("class2");  // Works
```

Yet...

```
propertyTwo.addClass("class2");  //Does not work
```

Can anyone help explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM element for propertyTwo must not exist at the time that `var propertyTwo = $('.links .active')` is called, whereas it does once `startup()` is called.

To confirm this, we'll need more information about your script. For example, what I previously described could occur if `MyObject` is created prior to the DOM being fully loaded, and then you call the `init()` method after the DOM is fully loaded (or at least after the element corresponding to `$('.links .active')` has been loaded.

Regardless, you should really focus on learning how to debug something like this along with why this specific attempt is not working. The main step in this process is to log to the console `propertyTwo` right after the line `var propertyTwo = $('.links .active')`. If the console shows `[]` (in Chrome at least), that means no elements were matched, which would support what I said is happening.

Comment: +1. jQuery's length/size are perfiect methods to diagnose such condition http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: Ah, you're right, and I think I know where you're going with this.  The 'active' class gets applied after the DOM is loaded (in another part of the script).  Is there any way I can still set that element as a property of my object?

Comment: Probably, but I'd need to see more code. Can you set the 'active' class prior to running the code you put in your post? That would be a pretty simple solution. If not, I'll really need to see more code (both HTML & JS) to offer further assistance.

Comment: @maxedison I've got it now.  The problem was that I was setting the value in the object's property to something that didn't exist in the DOM yet (just as you said).  I changed the script so that the variable starts out as '' and then reset it once the action that creates the element in the dom completed.  I understand this now, thanks = )